# Selenium xpath not clicking on Image link

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Im trying to use selenium to select the first result in a search.
[image]

To click on the first image im using xpath way to find the first result from the search.
The code is

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='category-search-wrapper']/div[2]/div/ol/li[1]/article/a")).click();
```

and from using the f12 and then ctrl f tools on the website it shows that I have the correct xpath

[image]

However, it is not clicking on the Image.
Here is the website that I am trying to test if it's any help.
https://www.dunnesstores.com/search?keywords=lamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` on the first result from the search you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.dunnesstores.com/search?keywords=lamp")
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("ol.product-list.product-list-main > li a"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.dunnesstores.com/search?keywords=lamp")
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ol[@class='product-list product-list-main']/li//a"))).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: dunnesstores]

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.dunnesstores.com/search?keywords=lamp')

accept = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                                        "#onetrust-accept-btn-handler")))

accept.click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
    '[class="c-product-card__link"]').click()
```

## You have to first click accept cookies , then find element using class or xpath or css

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='category-search-wrapper']/div[2]/div/ol/li[1]/article/a"))
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

With this code you avoid the elements that obscures it and the elements that are not disponible in your actual screen (out of scroll).